# AzureAD Set-AzureADUserExtension add array of values

Tags: azure-active-directory

We need to add array of values to a UserExtension. But according to doc userEcstension can only be a string. But if we look at the parsed JWT on the other side, the extension value is passed as an array.

How could i add multiple values under same extension name?
Right now we have this hacish solution where the value is a JSON array sting that will be parsed where needed.

```
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $UserId -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -ExtensionValue  '["Val1", "val2", "val3"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: Extension name values can be only set as string or single string value within an array but not as multiple values as separate elements in the array.

I tried to set the values of the extension attribute like below:

```
$existingExtensionValues = Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId UserID
$ExtensionName = "extension_30b4aef20a194b08afXXX_customerid"

# New values to add
$newValues = "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"

# Check if the extension property exists
if ($existingExtensionValues.$ExtensionName) {
    # If it exists, make sure the existing values are an array
    $existingValues = $existingExtensionValues.$ExtensionName -split ' '

    # Add new values to the existing array
    $existingValues += $newValues

    # Convert the array to a single string
    $updatedValue = $existingValues -join ' '

    # Set the updated values
    try {
        Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId UserID -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -ExtensionValue $updatedValue
    } catch {
        # Handle exceptions (confirmation prompts) here if needed
        Write-Host "Error: $_"
    }
} else {
    # If it doesn't exist, create a new array property with the new values
    $updatedValue = $newValues -join ' '

    # Set the updated values
    try {
        Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId 59aa8c6b-da61-43bd-9e3f-3889b2249c85 -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -ExtensionValue $updatedValue
    } catch {
        # Handle exceptions (confirmation prompts) here if needed
        Write-Host "Error: $_"
    }
}
```

[image]

But when I tried to check in decoded token, **the extension values are set as single string value within an array**:

It is always in the format [ "  "] and hence you cannot set extension attributes as multiple values like separate elements.

[image]

The token identifies the attribute as a string only, hence you can set the array/multiple values for **`Set-AzureADUserExtension`** but it will be considered as a string only.

Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduserextension?view=azureadps-2.0#syntax) which states that `ExtensionValue` must be a string.